# How to use alexa Alexa Voice Service in an Android App Like Amazon Shopping App

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Can anyone explain how to integrate alexa in my app just like amazon shopping app have integrated so that i can use my custom skill

Answer (score 0):

You must use the Alexa Voice Service (AVS) API from your Android app to achieve that. This is a sample project that directly accesses the AVS API from Android: https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid